# Snap points to points of different layer (based on attributes, not nearest)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, snapping, data-frame, pandas

I have 2 layer of points, PointLayer1 and PointLayer2. PointLayer1 has to be snapped to PointLayer2.

I have a table that has IDs of PointLayer1 that has to be snapped to PointLayer2.

Sample Table:

```
ID1        ID2
20         2445
22         2557
23         2456
```

At the end, all the nodes form PointLayer1 with ID1 has to be snapped to PointLayer2 with ID2.

Completed Code so far:

```
import pandas
import arcpy

all_snapped_nodes = 'all_snapped_nodes.shp'
all_new_nodes = 'AllnewNodes.shp'

new_old_node_conversion = pandas.read_csv('new_old_node_conversion.csv',index_col = 0, header = None)
#more code thats snaps IDs from layer1 to layer2.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will take three cursors and a couple dictionary. First iterate your id table, associating `id1` with `id2` in a dictionary. Then iterate new nodes and associate `id2s` with `xys`. Finally, iterate your all snapped feature class. Link `id1` to `id2` from your first dictionary, then `id2` to `xy` from your second.

```
import arcpy

all_snapped_nodes = 'all_snapped_nodes.shp'
all_new_nodes = 'AllnewNodes.shp'
snapTable = "SnapTable"

#create dictionary of id1 to id2
snapDi = {}
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (snapTable, ["ID1", "ID2"]) as curs:
    for id1, id2 in curs:
        snapDi [id1] = id2


#create dictionary with xy from new nodes by id
xyDi = {}
#spatial reference of all_snapped shapefile
sr = arcpy.Describe (all_snapped_nodes).spatialReference
#iterate all_new_nodes
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (all_new_nodes, ["ID", "SHAPE@XY"],
                            spatial_reference = sr) as curs:
    for id2, xy in curs:
        #update xy
        xyDi [id2] = xy

#update all_snapped_nodes
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (all_snapped_nodes, ["ID", "SHAPE@XY"]) as curs:
    for id1, xy in curs:
        #get id2
        try: id2 = snapDi [id1]
        except KeyError: continue
        #get xy of id2
        try: xy = xyDi [id2]
        except KeyError: continue
        row = (id1, xy)
        curs.updateRow (row)
```

Comment: from what I understood, you first created a dictionary of ID1 and ID2. Second, you generated xy coordinates of ID2. Third, you updated all_snapped_nodes to those calculated coordinates. Right? Where did the actual snapping occur? I am confused.

Comment: `SHAPE@XY` in an update cursor allows you to update xy coordinates. This is the snapping.

Comment: my coordinate system is WGS1984. Should I change the code for that??

Comment: I’m pretty sure the code will still work.